# Is it possible to create an HDF file solely in RAM and retrieve it as byte array?

Tags: c#, hdf5, hdf

Using HDF.PInvoke with C# I want to store data in an HDF5 file, but I do not want to immediately write the file to disk. Instead I want to pass the file as a byte array to a different class, which handles the interactions with a storage medium.

As far I can tell, this should be possible with the HDF CORE driver, since it allows you to create an HDF file in memory without writing it to a disk.

This is where I'm stuck:

```cs
public byte[] ConvertToHDF(object data)
{
    long fileID;

    // create HDF5 file, continuously growing in 0x1000 byte chunks
    {
        long propertyListFileAccess = H5P.create(H5P.FILE_ACCESS);
        H5P.set_fapl_core(propertyListFileAccess, (IntPtr)0x1000, 0);

        fileID = H5F.create("temporaryHDF", H5F.ACC_TRUNC,
            H5P.DEFAULT, propertyListFileAccess);

        H5P.close(propertyListFileAccess);
    }

    // store the data in the HDF file
    StoreHDF(fileID, data);

    // create byte array of fitting size
    ulong size = 0;
    H5F.get_filesize(fileID, ref size);
    byte[] binary = new byte[size];

    // fill binary with the HDF file
    ...

    return binary;
}
```

So is there a way to get the HDF file in the byte array without storing it on a disc? A solution where I had the HDF file in just one chunk and could simply use this instead of copying it to the byte array would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

Also, the means for obtaining the proper size of the byte array in the question is inaccurate, it may result in an array larger than necessary. The one below is precise.

Following code is meant to replace the code below `// create byte array of fitting size` and `// fill binary with the HDF file`

```
byte[] fileInRAM;

// make sure the HDF file is up to date
H5F.flush(fileID, H5F.scope_t.GLOBAL);

// retrieve copy H5F
{
    // create properly sized byte array for the file
    IntPtr sizePointer = (IntPtr)null;
    sizePointer = H5F.get_file_image(fileID, (IntPtr)null, ref sizePointer);
    fileInRAM = new byte[(int)sizePointer];

    // tell Garbage Collector to leave the byte array where it is
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(fileInRAM, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr filePointer = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

    // get file image
    H5F.get_file_image(fileID, filePointer, ref sizePointer);

    // allow the Garbage Collector to do its work again
    handle.Free();
}
```

source: https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/Advanced/FileImageOperations/HDF5FileImageOperations.pdf